# How do I populate a tableView with all the data in a dictionary?

Tags: swift, uitableview, dictionary

I have a struct which holds the data that I receive from a url. This code all works fine to the point of putting the data into a dictionary called clubDict but when it comes to displaying the data in a tableView, I get the count of the data in the dictionary but only get displayed one key and its different value properties repetitively.

```
struct Swifter: Codable {

let id: String?
let address: String?

}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var clubDict: [String: Swifter] = [:]

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let locationDict: Dictionary<String, Any> = ["latitude" : 53.444101, "longitude" : -2.192934]

    let json = ["location" : locationDict] as [String : Any]
    guard let clubLocatorURL = URL(string: "https://us-central1-geofire-46ce2.cloudfunctions.net/Club-Locator") else { return }

    var request = URLRequest(url: clubLocatorURL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .prettyPrinted) else { return }
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = httpBody

    let session = URLSession.shared

    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        if let response = response {
            print("Response: \(response)")
        }
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                self.clubDict = try decoder.decode([String: Swifter].self, from: data)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                }

            } catch {

                print("error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        }.resume()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return clubDict.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

for (key, value) in clubDict {
     cell.textLabel?.text = key
     cell.detailTextLabel?.text = value.address

}

    return cell
}
}
```

Comment: Your way to display data in the table is wrong. `cellForRowAt` is called multiple times, once for each index path (the `indexPath` parameter). Usually an array is used as data source. It's supposed to get the object for the index path form the array and display the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tableView displays stuff in order. A dictionary isn't ordered. By looping over your dictionary with "for (key, value) in clubDict" you will only get the last entry in the dictionary to be displayed.

What you have to do is get the unordered dictionary into an ordered form like an array. For example like so:

```
let dict = ["key1" : "value1"]; // Your dictionary. Use the one you already have
var arr : [(String, String)] = [];
for (key, value) in dict {
    arr.append((key, value));
}
```

Then you will have to adjust the "numberOfRowsInSection" method to now use arr.count

For each cell the cellForRowAtIndexPath method will be called.
There you extract the correct entry from the array by its index:

```
let (key, value) = arr[indexPath.row]; //read element for the desired cell
cell.textLabel?.text = key
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = value.address
```

You have to adjust the datatypes to your needs. I just took a dictionary of String:String

Comment: If I sort data and load it into a dictionary it is ordered, isn't it?

Comment: No it isnt as in a dictionary does not represent an array-like structure with an index. You can't say "I want the first element of a dictionary". Which one would it be? The one where the key is the lowest alphabetically? What if the key is another object?
Just like sets, a dictionary is just "a cloud" of things. Their "index" is their key.

Comment: Forgive me, but I think you are mistaken.

Comment: @MartinMuldoon TMob is right. A dictionary is unordered by definition.

Comment: I'm always interested in learning new things. Please elaborate :)